# Adding different drop downs to inbox tab and trash tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, drop-down-menu

I have a section within a page which displays messages/notifications to a user.

I have 2 tabs at the top labelled "Inbox" and "Trash". I also have a separate dropdown menu on the page which when clicking on the "Inbox" tab the dropdowns read "Mark as read, Mark as Unread, Move to trash".

I have this working on the dropdown for Inbox, but I need the dropdown menu items to change if the user clicks on "Trash". I need these to read "Move to inbox, Remove".

At the moment if I click on the Inbox tab or Trash tab, the dropdowns values are the same.

Below is my code for the tabs:

```
<div class="event_line line" style="width:100%;">
       <div class="unit size1of2"><a href="javascript://" id="inbox" title="INBOX" class="my_events_status_toogle selected">INBOX</a></div>
       <div class="unit size1of2"><a href="javascript://" id="trash" title="TRASH" class="my_events_status_toogle">TRASH</a></div>
</div>
```

---

Below is my code for the Dropdown menu:

```
<div id="actions_panel" style="float:right; margin-top:-10px;">
    <ul>
        <li class="menu_item"><a title="Actions" href="#"><img border="0" alt="Actions" src="images/icons/action_panel_icon.gif"></a>
            <ul class="sub_menu dropShadow">
                <li><a href="#" id="inbox" title="Mark as read">Mark as read</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" id="inbox" title="Mark as unread">Mark as unread</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" id="inbox" title="Move to Trash">Move to Trash</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" id="trash" title="Move to Trash">Move to Trash</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" id="trash" title="Remove">Remove</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Separate the menu into two, one for the inbox stuff, one for trash. Then, when clicking on one of the anchors, toggle the corresponding menu. Also, you're duplicating IDs in the code above, IDs must be unique

Comment: can u provide a jsfiddle for your above code??

Comment: I've put together a rough jsfiddle. You can see on rollover of the blank image the dropdown is the same http://jsfiddle.net/4wr8H/

Answer (score 0):

I have done in jsfiddle with your code reference. Check it out the below jsfiddle.

```
 $('.unit a').click(function(){    
clname ="."+$(this).attr('id');
$('.actions_panel').css("display","none");
$(clname).css("display","block");
});
```

[**UPDATED JSFIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/vX6tY/1/)

Comment: Hi Suresh, thanks for this. I'm going to try and add what you've done to my code and see what happens!

Comment: Hi Suresh, thatnks, your code really helped.Just one thing, do you know how I can make the image for the dropdown always appear? At the moment the dropdown only appears if I click on "Inbox" or "Trash", but I need to appear all the time.

Comment: i have updated my jsfiddle above. check it out. Not sure understand properly.

Comment: Thanks Suresh. I think the reason it isn't displaying the dropdown all the time is because the actions_panel class is set to display:none.